# Como fazer herança de Models no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, herança

Considerando que tenha as Models `Pessoa` e `Usuario`, e que um `Usuario` **é uma** `Pessoa` (`Usuario extends Pessoa`), ou `Usuario belongsTo Pessoa` e `Pessoa hasOne Usuario`.

É possível que o `Usuario` tenha os mesmos atributos e métodos de `Pessoa` sem fazer `$usuario->pessoa->metodo`, simplesmente fazendo `$usuario->metodo`?

Comment: é relação 1 para 1? você quer ?

Comment: O relacionamento eu sei fazer, mas queria poder usar herança de classes ...

Comment: entendi !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Olha eu precisaria testar o comportamente porque ai são dois models neh pela sua questão !!!

Comment: os dois já herdam do Eloquent correto essa afirmação? se for não dá!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não funciona assim no Laravel.

Relacionamentos são representados da seguinte forma (no seu caso):

```
class Usuario extends Eloquent {
    public function belongsTo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Usuario');
    }
}

class Pessoa extends Eloquent {
    public function hasOne()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Usuario');
    }
}
```

Quanto aos métodos e/ou propriedades, você tem acesso a todos do objeto relacionado (Eloquent) porém referentes ao Eloquent/Model.

Caso queira fazer algo mais específico, você deve usar os conceitos/metodologias referentes a:

- Injeção de Dependência (DI)
- IoC
- S.O.L.I.D

Por exemplo, trabalhando com **Repositórios (Repositories/Factories)**, como quase tudo é isolado da estrutura básica (mvc), você terá por exemplo "n" repositórios com os métodos necessários/vinculados a qualquer classe, com isso você pode acessá-los de qualquer "lugar".

Creio que pesquisando sobre os conceitos acima você conseguirá chegar onde deseja.

Recomendo adquirir uma assinatura do [Laracasts do incrível Jeffrey Way](http://laracasts.com).

Answer (score 0):

Considere que relacionamento não é a mesma coisa que herança, quando você define relacionamento entre models, não tem nada a ver com herança de métodos e atributos.

Para criar herança entre models, você precisa extendê-los desta forma:

```
class Evento{
     var $table = 'eventos';
}

class Reuniao extends Evento{

}
```

Comment: Aí não funciona, se ela extender de outra classe, não dá, considere que não extendi Evento de Eloquent.

Comment: Mas ele pode criar uma composição e compartilhar métodos entre as classes, certo?